# How to close and open access to SQL Server 2008 in Windows application?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm using ***SQL Server 2008*** (without application server or anything).

Numbers of users can be up to 1000. ***Windows Authentication*** is used.

The question is:

How to handle modes, so

1. some users will be allowed to work
       in read-only mode
2. some users won't
               have access to db for some time

My versions:

1. Using a table with a mode id for
   every group of users, that will work
   the same way. On Form Load
   application will query that table
   for mode id.
2. Using trigger on the tables, that
   must work according to that mode.
   The trigger will query mode value
   and doesn't work if access is closed
   or it's in read-only mode

I know these are not the best solutions, that's why I'm asking for your advice.

There's one more point.

If the mode is changed to `"access-is-closed"` for a group of users, that group must not be able to query to *DB* starting that moment.

With first solution I wrote it won't work, because user can be in application at that moment and no form load event will work. How can I do this?

Is there any optimal solution?

Thank you. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends somewhat on how you Access app interacts with the server, but for number 1 why not just use the built in Role/User permissions system in SQL Server?

For number 2, as your using Windows Authentication you can restrict logon hours in active directory on a [per-account/OU basis](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc781861%28WS.10%29.aspx) this should prevent them from logging on to SQL server.

You could also do it via [Logon Triggers](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326598%28SQL.105%29.aspx) which would not also prevent access to other domain resources.

Comment: How it interacts? What do you mean? Application opens a connection on log in and keeps it open. What else do you need to know?
for number 1, we're going to use sql users, but it's not so easy. There're more than 20 small or large applications, that need to be changed and 1000 users that need to be created with their roles and everything. For number 2, we don't need to restrict logon hours. It's like someone presses a button and at that moment access is closed for all users. It's not a specific time.
Logon Trigger is very interesting, but if I got it right, it's logs out from windows, not DB.

Comment: 2. You can deny a SQL authenticated logon with a logon trigger to prevent the user logging on to the db, for example; http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlsecurity/thread/08e49a1a-8c5b-43c8-83ef-edb661d19602

Comment: Is it easy to add or remove logon trigger from app?